# how to mage the submenu open on wordpress active page

Tags: menus, sub-menu, activation

i have the same problem in my website click [here](http://clisho.com/dante/)
how i can change the code for when you click on corporate profile you go to the page and the sub menu stay open

please some help

Comment: Please read [ask], file an [edit] and fix your question.

Answer (score 0):

When on the Corporate profile page, that menu item has the following classes: `current_page_item current-menu-ancestor current_page_ancestor`. Any of these are attached to a menu item when you are on that page, or a child page.

Target these in your stylesheet, and set the `.sub-container` div to have `display:block;`. That should do the trick.

Also, your menu appears to be animated by some JS, I suggest perhaps doing the displaying of the submenu within that same JS file.